# Cannot read zip file from HttpInputStream using DotNetZip 1.9

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetzip

I am trying to use DotNetZip 1.9 to read an uploaded zip file in Asp.Net MVC 3.
I already verified that the HttpPostedFileBase object I receive is fine.  I can save it to disk and then unzip it.  However, saving to disk first seemed wasteful since I should be able to unzip from memory directly.

From MSDN, the HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream Property "gets a Stream object that points to an uploaded file to prepare for reading the contents of the file".

According to DetNetZip references, ZipFile.Read() can accept a Stream object.  So I tried it and DotNetZip throws a BadReadException.  I have attached screen shots showing the problem.

Problem unzipping from HttpInputStream
[image: Problem unzipping from HttpInputStream]

Value of the InputStream, Length matches that of the uploaded zip file
[image: Value of the InputStream, Length matches that of the uploaded zip file]

Help anyone?  Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that the `ZipFile.IsZipFile` method call has advanced your `InputStream` position and when you try to read it later it is no longer a valid zip file since the stream position has moved. Try sticking a

```
fileData.InputStream.Position = 0;
```

just after verifying that the stream is a valid zip file and just before the `using` clause in which you attempt to read it. This will reset the stream position at the beginning.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.  So stupid that I didn't notice it.  Thanks a lot for your help!